# What's the default administrator password for a FORE ES-2810 or an ASX-1000 switch?

Tags: switch, password, password-recovery

Trying to get to know a new (to me) network and found an entire rack full of FORE ES-2810 and ASX-1000 switches still being used for... something. When I telnet to one of them, it asks for an administrator password -- which I don't have. From what I can tell, FORE was bought out at some point by Marconi.

Does anyone know what the default administrator password is for one of these switches? If not, I suppose my next question would be how to perform password recovery on these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
username: ami 
password: none
```

This came from [here](http://www.phenoelit-us.org/dpl/dpl.html).

Answer (score 0):

Oh-- the ES-2610 is the FORE switch that's a rebranded Intel 510T. Zow. I worked with a boatload of those years ago.

I had a set of manuals, firmwares, etc, but I've long since deleted them. This guy appears to have some information about them here: http://www.ice.mtu.edu/~jamyles/es-2810/

You might be able to load Intel 510T firmware on them-- I dunno how changed they were from the original 510T. They're actually a fairly decent switch.

I can't help you on the ASX-1000. Never touched any of those.

Hopefully you don't end up neck deep in ATM. Ick. FORE was big on ATM. I'm so glad that ATM "lost".

Comment: I'm hoping I can get rid of it quickly.. but first need to know what it's doing.

Comment: Hopefully the manuals there help you. I'm been trying to recall what the 510T management interface looked like, but I'm not coming up with anything. It's just been too many years! *smile*